# How to demosaic a picamera raw image with rawpy?

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, libraw, demosaicing

I am attempting to stack long exposures from a Pi NoIR camera.

The picamera raw format can be unpacked into a numpy array based on the example: http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html#raw-bayer-data-captures

How can this numpy array be to converted to a rawpy (https://github.com/letmaik/rawpy) image to postprocess and demosaic?

Comment: Did you try to load the image file directly with rawpy? rawpy is based on libraw, which is based on dcraw, and it seems to have some support for it: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=92562&p=647559

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. The original goal was to stack the raw images as they were taken as a numpy array and demosaic it once at the end. The results from demosaicing and stacking the 16-bit tiffs was good enough considering the image quality from the Pi Camera modules.